# SELECT query where 1 column equals 2 variables

Tags: mysql, sql

The issue:
I want to select the products which have the option_value_id of both 1 and 3. But, as you can see, it will also show the products which have only have 1 of the option_value_ids.

I tried adding AND instead of IN but that will obviously show no results.

The answer might be simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out at the moment.
Could someone help me out? Even a small hint can be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: woah so colourful, what is this platform sql resting on?

Comment: @bonCodigo : looks like the modern gui of a new phpMyAdmin

Comment: Not sure if @bonCodigo is being sarcastic, but it's PHPMyAdmin 3.5.2.2.

Comment: oh, ofcourse I wasn't sarcastic at all. It really is catchy. And I was even wondering if you are running it on a mac... ;) (if there's a possibility to run MYSql on mac..)

Comment: Nope, I never worked with a Mac.
You should be able to run PHPMyAdmin on any web server, as long as it has MySQL running. There's LAMP/MAMP for Mac. But I guess this goes a bit off-topic hehe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [*Relation Division*](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), and here is one way to do so:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEName 
WHERE Product_ID IN(SELECT Product_ID
            FROM Tablename
            WHERE option_value_id IN(1, 3)
            GROUP BY Product_ID
            HAVING COUNT(option_value_id) = 2);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0214/5)

This will give you:

```
| ID | PRODUCT_ID | OPTION_VALUE_ID |
-------------------------------------
|  1 |          1 |               1 |
|  3 |          1 |               3 |
| 13 |          2 |               3 |
| 14 |          2 |               1 |
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it should return the product_id 1, 2 and 12. 
As you can see, product_id 1, 2 and 12 have option_value_id 1 and 3.

Comment: @user1961685 product_id 12 doesn't have both 1 and 2 it has only 3 in the sample data. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is example of looking at things as a set.  I think the best approach is to use SQL's aggregation, particularly the having clause.  In MySQL syntax, this looks like:

```
select pa.product_id
from Product_Attributes pa
group by pa.product_id
having max(pa.option_value_id = 1) = 1 and
       max(pa.option_value_id = 3) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, called Relational Division, there is even a tag in SO for it: **[sql-match-all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-match-all?sort=votes)**

Usually, there is a unique constraint on the `(product_id, option_value_id)`, so one solution is to use 2 joins (N joins if you want to check for N attributes):

```
SELECT p.*                 -- whatever columns you need 
FROM product AS p          -- from the `product` table
  JOIN products_attributes AS pa1
    ON  pa1.option_value_id = 1
    AND pa1.product_id = p.product_id
  JOIN products_attributes AS pa2
    ON  pa2.option_value_id = 3
    AND pa2.product_id = p.product_id ;
```

There is a similar question, with more than 10 different ways to achieve the same result (and benchmarks for Postgres): **[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products_attributes 
WHERE option_value_id IN (1, 3) 
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```